# Running different versions of the same binary, same file

Tags: unix, ubuntu

I have a single binary that can run in server or client mode.  It can be used like this:

```
$ ./a.out --server &
$ ./a.out --client &
```

They talk to each other, and this is working well.  My question is what is the expected behavior when I launch the server:

```
$ ./a.out --server &
```

But then I forget to kill it, and go about my development work, editing and building, and running the client:

```
$ edit client.c
$ make
$ ./a.out --client
^C
<repeat>
```

Now without the sticky bit set, is my OS (Ubuntu) running two different versions of my binary?  Or is it taking a shortcut and using the in-memory instance and therefore ignoring my latest build?  Are there any other side effects to this mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make` replaces the executable by deleting the original file. However, since it is executing in the background, there is a reference to it. The file isn't completely deleted until the reference is cleared (though directory entries are cleared to make way for the new executable file).

So, in your example there are two versions of the program running. One side-effect is if you make changes which cause major incompatibility b/w your server & client code - such as changes in packet structures. You'll probably see weird, unexplainable behavior, crashes, etc. Its always a good idea to kill the background server and re-run your entire test.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I feared, and did in fact see.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not change server code, the just copy your a.out into 'my_server' e.g. Then run it as my_server --server. make will replace a.out, but not my_server.

Another way - tell make to kill all running a.out-s just before recompile: add target 'all' (it must be first in makefile), which depends on a.out and executes 'killall a.out'.